Example of a wide fully-faithful functor that is not an isomorphism.
Given a functor $T:C \to D$ between two categories, we say that $T$ is wide if it is surjective on objects, full if all functions between Hom-sets $T_{x,y}:C(x,y) \to D(Tx,Ty)$ are surjective, and faithful if all functions between Hom-sets is injective.
The forgetful functor from topological spaces is an example of a wide and faithful functor that is not an isomorphism, but it is not full. Could you provide an example of a functor surjective on objects that is fully-faithful but not an isomorphism?
I have been trying to come up with examples, but every time I find a functor that is surjective but not injective on objects, it fails to be either faithful or full.

You can construct artificial examples pretty easily, e.g: Let $2$ be the discrete category on two objects and $1$ that on one. Then the unique functor $2 \to 1$ satisfies your criteria.

@BenSteffan that functor is not full, as the unique morphism $\mathrm{id} : F(a) \to F(b)$ doesn't come from a morphism $a \to b$ in $2$.

@NaïmFavier ...right, that was silly of me. Thank you for pointing that out.


Could you provide an example of a functor surjective on objects that is fully-faithful but not an isomorphism?

Every example arises from collapsing down isomorphism classes of objects. The difficulty is how to do this in a way that actually produces a surjective fully faithful functor; here's an example. Take $X$ to be the category whose

objects are pairs $(V, B)$ of a finite-dimensional real vector space $V$ and a basis $B$, and
morphisms $(V, B) \to (W, C)$ are linear maps $T : V \to W$ (note that there is no condition involving the bases)

and $Y$ to be the category $\text{Mat}$ whose objects are the Euclidean spaces $\mathbb{R}^n$ and whose morphisms are matrices (equivalently, linear maps between these). Then take $F : X \to Y$ to be the functor sending $(V, B)$ to $\mathbb{R}^{\dim V}$ and sending a linear map to its matrix with respect to the provided bases. This functor just has the effect of collapsing down each isomorphism class of finite-dimensional vector space to $\mathbb{R}^n$.
This kind of thing is why we talk about equivalences of categories, not isomorphisms; $F$ ought to be an equivalence in any reasonable sense of the word, and it is, but it isn't an isomorphism.

 There's a funny subtlety here worth noting. $X$ is actually itself equivalent to the category $\text{Vect}_f(\mathbb{R})$ of finite-dimensional real vector spaces, via the functor which just forgets the basis, but there is no obvious way to directly write down a functor $\text{Vect}_f(\mathbb{R}) \to \text{Mat}$ even though these categories must also be equivalent. It is possible to write such a functor down but it requires using the axiom of global choice to choose a basis of every finite-dimensional vector space. You might consider this unsatisfying; if so see anafunctors.

The above example can be generalized as follows. Let $C$ be any category and let $\text{Skel}(C)$ be any full subcategory of $C$ containing exactly one object from each isomorphism class (this is a skeleton of $C$). Let $C'$ be the category whose objects are pairs $(c, i)$ of an object $c \in C$ and an isomorphism $i$ between $c$ and an object in $\text{Skel}(C)$, and whose morphisms are the morphisms in $C$ (ignoring the isomorphisms). Then there is a functor $F : C' \to \text{Skel}(C)$ obtained by applying the isomorphisms $i$, as above, which is again surjective on objects and fully faithful but not an isomorphism unless $C$ is itself skeletal. But $F$ is always an equivalence.

Just to be explicit: under your generalisation, $\mathrm{Vect}_f(\mathbb{R})$ is $C$, $X$ is $C'$ and $\mathrm{Mat}$ is $\mathrm{Skel}(C)$, right?

@Naïm: yes, that's what I had in mind.

I would like to add that you can write down a functor $\mathrm{Mat} \to \mathrm{Vect}_f(\mathbb{R})$ without any choice and prove that it is fully faithful and essentially surjective on objects (but not split eso, which is why there's only an anafunctor going the other way). (Perhaps another way to make sense of this failure is that $\mathrm{Mat}$ is not a univalent category.)

I have one question, is this transformation functorial? What if I take the same space $V$ with two different basis $B,C$ then the identity function in $V$ won't be mapped to the identity matrix in $\mathbb R^n$ with respect to the two different basis.

@Daniel: that's right. That's what happens when you express the identity function in two different bases! Those two objects are not the same object in $X$ so that function is not an identity morphism. It only becomes an identity morphism after applying the functor $X \to \text{Vect}$ which forgets the bases.

Let me say something else: in HoTT, assuming $C$ is a univalent category (such as $\mathrm{Vect}f(\mathbb{R})$), then $F$ is an isomorphism of precategories, because $\Sigma{c : |C|} \Sigma_{s : |\mathrm{Skel}(C)|} c \cong s$ contracts away to $|\mathrm{Skel}(C)|$. On the other hand, the inclusion $\mathrm{Skel}(C) \to C$ is not an equivalence, because global choice contradicts univalence. So I would argue that your "subtlety" is actually a much better counterexample. (I've formalised this here for finite sets instead of finite-dim vector spaces.)

The examples that Naïm Favier and Qiaochu Yuan give in their answers are perfectly fine, but let me give a class of examples that occur "in the wild" in algebraic topology: To any topological space $X$ we associate a category $\Pi_1 X$, its fundamental groupoid, with objects the points of $X$ and morphisms homotopy classes of paths, i.e. an element of $\operatorname{Hom}_{\Pi_1 X}(x, y)$ is a homotopy class of paths $[0, 1] \to X$ starting at $x$ and ending at $y$ relative $\{0, 1\}$. Composition is simply given by path concatenation.
The assignment $\mathrm{Top} \to \mathrm{Cat}$, $X \mapsto \Pi_1 X$ is functorial: Given a continous map $f\colon X \to Y$, it is not hard to check that the assignment $\Pi_1 f\colon \Pi_1 X \to \Pi_1 Y$ sending $x \in X = \operatorname{ob} \Pi_1 X$ to $f(x)$ and a homotopy class of paths $[\gamma] \in \operatorname{Hom}_{\Pi_1 X}(x, y)$ to $[f \circ \gamma]\in \operatorname{Hom}_{\Pi_1 Y}(f(x), f(y))$ yields a functor. Moreover, if $f$ is a homotopy equivalence then $\Pi_1 f$ is an equivalence of categories, in particular fully faithful, and since it is wide iff $f$ is surjective any surjective but non-bijective homotopy equivalence yields an example of what you're looking for. For instance, you could consider $f = \mathrm{pr}_X\colon X \times \mathbb{R} \to X$, the projection map onto the first factor, for any nonempty space $X$, or the unique map $D^n \to *$ from the $n$-dimensional disk to a point.

The category I wrote down is perfectly natural! It's the category you have to write down to give a complete answer to the question of in what precise sense you can assume that finite-dimensional real vector spaces are $\mathbb{R}^n$ WLOG. It is even related to your example if you take $X$ to be an infinite-dimensional Grassmannian (a "moduli space of vector spaces").

@QiaochuYuan The issue with your example (to me) is that your maps are not related to the additional structure you introduce: You differentiate between $(\mathbb{R}^2, {e_1, e_2})$ and $(\mathbb{R}^2, {e_1, 2e_2})$ but your maps are still just linear maps, no strings attached. ...but I get your point, I'll edit my answer :)

But this is exactly how we argue that we can understand all linear maps in terms of matrices!

There are foundational subtleties associated with this question, but under one reasonable interpretation, you are asking for a fully faithful and essentially surjective on objects (eso) functor that is not an equivalence of categories; assuming suitable foundations, this is impossible, i.e. every fully faithful eso functor is an equivalence of categories.
If you really mean isomorphism of strict categories, then take $C$ to be the contractible category with two objects and $D$ the terminal category (with one object and one morphism). Then the unique functor $F : C \to D$ is an equivalence of categories (hence fully faithful, essentially surjective and essentially injective), but not an isomorphism (it fails to be strictly injective on objects).

Are you taking "isomorphism" to mean "equivalence," and if so why?

Because I adhere to the convention that categories aren't strict unless specified so, and equivalence is the correct notion of sameness between general categories. I'll add an edit for the strict case.

Here's an example of a functor that is wide, full, and faithful.
It's slightly less trivial than just having all the homsets be singletons.
Let $C$ be the freest category with two objects $X$ and $Y$ subject to the constraints below and generated by the following countably infinite families of morphisms

$f_\mathbb{N} : X \to X$
$g_\mathbb{N} : X \to Y$
$h_\mathbb{N} : Y \to Y$
$j_\mathbb{N} : Y \to X$

Here are the constraints:
For any two finite composition of primitive arrows $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$ such the compositions are in the same homset, $\vec{a} = \vec{b}$ if and only if:

They have the same number of non-identity primitive arrows.
The indices of the non-identity primitive arrows are the same. So, $f_1 \circ f_7 \circ f_3$ = $j_1 \circ g_7 \circ f_3$.

Let $D$ be the free category with one object $Z$ generated by the following countably infinite family of morphisms:

$k_\mathbb{N} : Z \to Z$.

I now define a functor $F : C \to D$.

$F(X)$ is $Z$.
$F(Y)$ is $Z$.
$F(a_i)$ is $k_i$ where $a$ is $f, g, h$ or $j$.

Let's check all the conditions.

$F$ is a functor since it preserves the identity and preserves composition.
$F$ is a bijection on all the homsets, a composition of primitive arrows corresponding to any finite sequence of natural numbers in any homset in $C$ is sent to the composition of primitive arrows corresponding to the same sequence of natural numbers in the sole homset of $D$.
$F$ is surjective on objects. There's one object in $D$ and we hit it.

